# Does filter chain get interrupted if you redirect in the action?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, filter

So let's say I have a before_filter, an action, and an after_filter.

I know from this page [Filter class](http://rails.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/Filters/ClassMethods.html) that if you redirect in the before_filter the filter chain is broken. However what happens if you redirect in the action? Does the after_filter still get run or does that break the filter chain too?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Redirecting within the action shouldn't halt the filter chain, only a redirect in a before or around filter will prevent the after filter from being executed. Halting the filters can only happen within a filter, not within the action.